# Check if a session variable is set

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to check if a certain variable is set inside my template...if it is set, an image will be displayed...I have written this as below in my template, but apparently it's not working.

```
{% if request.session.chosen_year %}
    <a href="/undo_year/">
       <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/undo.gif" border="0" alt="Reset" />
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a `RequestContext` so that the request is passed into the template context?

Comment: this fixed it...thanks again Daniel.  I have to keep remembering this...I always forget it